# Problem with insertion at a certain point in linked list with inherited functions in C++

Tags: c++, list, class, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to insert a number at a certain position in a linked list. However I cannot access the next pointer normally because it is a private member, and have to use a `getNext` function. I am unsure of how to assign next pointers with this function as it gives me errors.

```
#pragma once

class IntListNode {
public:
    IntListNode(int e, IntListNode *nextptr): 
        elem(e), next(nextptr) { }
    int &getElement() {return elem;}
    IntListNode *getNext() {return next;}
private:
    int elem;                   // linked list element value
    IntListNode *next;          // next item in the list
};
```

This is the code I have attempted but I keep receiving errors.

```
void IntegerList::AddAtPosition(int num, int placement)
{
    IntListNode* temp1 = head;

    IntListNode* temp2 = head;

    temp1->getElement() = num;

    if (placement == 0)
    {
        head = temp1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < placement - 2; i++)
        {
            temp2 = temp2->getNext();
        }
        temp1->getNext() = temp2->getNext();
        temp2->getNext() = temp1;
        //THe Lines getting errors
    }

}
```

Error message:

> E0137 "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Comment: http://www.fullerton.edu/ecs/cs/resources/files/IntListNode.h

Comment: http://www.fullerton.edu/ecs/cs/resources/files/IntegerList.h

Comment: Those are the files that are in the program

Comment: Links rot and are not available to all users If the question needs the information contained in the link to be understood, the link contents must be in the question itself.  Prefer to craft a [mcve] to overwhelming people with code. The true beauty of the [mcve] is after a few rounds of Divide and Conquer making the [mcve], you usually find the error yourself.

Comment: Free clue: you can obviously assign to the return value of `getElement()`. Take a few moments to think about why, what's so special about `getElement()`, and then you will be able to figure out your problem, all by yourself. Keep staring at `getElement()` until you figure it out.

Comment: In addition, remember the what the section on pass by reference and pass by value in your text book said about copies. The same applies to return values.

Comment: There are some bugs in this code, and some violations of common -- and sensible -- conventions. Do you want to understand what's going wrong, or just get the code to work?

Comment: I'd like to understand what I am doing wrong so I can get the code to work

Comment: @Beta if you're able to tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be really appreciated

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't suppose you're able to give me another hint? I still can't understand how to solve this

Comment: it is unusual to have a method called getXX to assign to a member variable since it is a bit confusing for the user of your class - get implies that you only read from it. Normally one would have a function setXX for changing the value .

Comment: You didn't mention in your question that you were forbidden to modify some parts of the code. I can explain the mistakes I see, and how I would get the code to work, but my solution won't be much good if I violate a "house rule" I didn't know about. Please edit your question to state what you're allowed to do.

Comment: @Beta Okay thanks will do for next time!!!! Definitely should of mentioned that. another user helped me figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `getNext()` method to this: `IntListNode*& getNext() {return next;}`.

The `IntListNode *getNext()` version will return the value of `next` member but not it's address so this line is not modifiable: `tempX->getNext() = tempY`;

---

**Edit**

Based on the restrictions/conditions mentioned by the OP, I can think of only way to this is:

```
*temp1 = IntListNode(temp1->getElement(), temp2->getNext());
*temp2 = IntListNode(temp2->getElement(), temp1);
```

Comment: That line of code was provided for me so I have to solve it without modifying it.

Comment: i updated the answer due to wrong code. it's fixed now. though i didn't test to run it.

Comment: I cannot change the method as it was the code given in the problem. Is there a way to access the next pointer without changing the getNext Method?

Comment: are you not allowed to add method in `IntListNode` like `setNext(IntListNode* newNextPtr)`? it seems the only way to modify the `next` based on the class given is via the constructor method.